# How is this ARM (Thumb) LDR Instruction being calculated?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, thumb

The code is running on a Cortex M0+.  I am trying to calculate the addresses of LDR PC-related loads and am finding the addresses are not always consistent.

This LDR PC-related load does not follow any of the other LDR PC-related loads I have calculated so far.  How was this address calculated step-by-step?  Kindly, please provide supporting documentation as I have not seen this documented anywhere.

**"Add 4 here", "Add 8 here", "use the next PC"** are the typical answers however I am finding those answers do not provide consistent or correct results.

Here is the (Thumb) LDR instruction

`ldr  r3, [pc, #4] ;`

[image]

Thumb instruction definition for a PC-relative load (ignore the highlight)

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Here are **correct** calculations.

Example 1: `0x1000'0306: LDR.N R4, [PC, #0xc0]`

<s>Wrong Calculated Address: `0x1000'0306 + 0x4 + 0xc0 = 0x1000'03CA`</s>

**Correct Calculated Address: `0x1000'0306->clear bit[0]->0x1000'0304 + 0x4 + 0xc0 = 0x1000'03C8`**

[image]

Example 2: `0x1000'0306: LDR.N R4, [PC, #0xc8]`

<s>Wrong Calculated Address: `0x1000'0306 + 0x4 + 0xc8 = 0x1000'03D2`</s>

**Correct Calculated Address: `0x1000'0306->clear bit[0]->0x1000'0304 + 0x4 + 0xc8 = 0x1000'03D0`**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excerpt you quote seems to explain it pretty clearly, paying attention to the Notes:  Add 4 to the address of the `ldr` instruction, clear bit 1 of the result, and add the immediate.

In this example:

- The instruction is at address 0x1000451c.
- Add 4 to get 0x10004520.
- Clear bit 1 of this value.  Here it's already 0, so nothing happens.  (Or to phrase it another way, round down to a multiple of 4.  Since 0x10004520 is already a multiple of 4, nothing happens.)
- Add 4 (the value of the immediate) to get 0x10004524.

Which agrees with what the disassembler is telling you.

Comment: The only pattern I'm seeing is that LDR may use the next program counter address that lands on a word-aligned address (32-bit DWORD). For example, PC=0x2 will use 0x0, PC=0x6 will use 0x4, PC=0xA will use 0x8, PC=0xE will use 0xC.  This is only a guess.  I have no basis for this other than what I have observed so far and tried to determine.

Comment: I recalculated everything and what you said is exactly what it's doing. The document is correct. I was doing math wrong. The math of clearing bit[1] and the rounding down to a multiple of 4 is correct. Thank you for your help!